# Jquery click not working on dropdown menu

Tags: php, jquery, onclick

I have a search similar to Google's that dropsdown with results while the user is typing.  Ideally I would like for the user to click on one of these results and the value goes into the searchbox.  However, when i click on the results, nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='topicInput' name='topic' autocomplete='off' />
<div id='tagResult'></div>  //this is the dropdown
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#topicInput').keyup(function(){

        var topic = $(this).val();
        if (topic==''){
            $('#tagResult').css("display" , "none");
        }
        else{
            //$('div').click(function(){
                //$('#tagResult').css("display" , "none");

            //});
            $('#tagResult').css("display" , "block");

                $.post('../topic.php' , {topic: topic} , function(response){

                $('#tagResult').html(response);     
                });
            }
    });
     //the above code is working properly

$('.topicResult').click(function(){
    alert(1);   //this is just a test, but it never shows up
});
```

So, when i click on a .topicResult nothing happens.  An alert should show up.  I have verified that topic.php does in fact return divs with the topicResult class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're binding your click event and then adding elements to the page after the listener is bound. It won't fire.

Two options

**Option 1, use a listener that can bind to elements after the page is rendered**

Either change the click event for .topicResult to use ".on()" for jQuery 1.7+ or use ".live() or .delegate()" for previous versions

```
 $(document).on('click','.topicResult',function(){
      alert('1');
 )};
```

**Option 2, move your click bind so it is bound after you add the elements**

```
 $('#topicInput').keyup(function(){ 

    var topic = $(this).val(); 
    if (topic==''){ 
        $('#tagResult').css("display" , "none"); 
    } 
    else{ 
        //$('div').click(function(){ 
            //$('#tagResult').css("display" , "none"); 

        //}); 
        $('#tagResult').css("display" , "block"); 

            $.post('../topic.php' , {topic: topic} , function(response){ 

            $('#tagResult').html(response);
                $('.topicResult').click(function(){ 
                      alert(1);   //this is just a test, but it never shows up 
                 }); 

            }); 
        } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the click event after the result's come back - where it is, you're attaching it to nothing.

Try something like:

```
 $.post('../topic.php' , {topic: topic} , function(response){

    $('#tagResult').html(response);    

    $('.topicResult').click(function(){
        alert(1);   //this is just a test, but it never shows up
    }); 
});
```